# How to fix blue screen of death (BSOD) error?

Tags: bsod

am very sure that my graphics card nvidia geforce 210 is causing BSOD, because when i remove the graphic card and use the on-board graphics there are no such errors.

I have got 3 BSODs up to date. the 3 dump files are
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-Hpowxg3qbDcDM5ckhzbWlsbm8/edit?usp=sharing

Please go through the dump files and help me fix the issue.

thank you in advance.

Comment: What drivers were loaded at the time the ue screen happened you can use BlueScreenViewer to unclude this information in your question.  What version of windows asking us to download dump files is a lot for some people

Comment: "Please go through the dump files and help me fix the issue." -- Wow, -1.

Comment: going through the dump files is optional. So am not forcing you to go through right? So cool. @techie007

Comment: The Intel driver **igxpdv32.dll** causes the issue. Yours is from 2008. find a newer Intel GPU driver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, make sure all of your drivers are up to date (mobo drivers especially). 2nd, go to the manufacturer's website (not Nvidia's website), and download the drivers. I have an ASUS GeForce 210 silent - and the Nvidia's website drivers crash my system almost 100% of the time. Using ASUS's drivers, I have no issues.

I found this article.

http://www.tomshardware.com/answers/id-1654597/graphic-card-crashes-causing-bsod.html.

Comment: Ok. even i have asus geforce 210. But i have installed drivers from nvidia website. So can u provide a link to asus geforce 210 driver update?

Comment: @user3249242 - They would be located on Asus product page for your motherboard.  You provided none of that information, so even if I felt like looking for you, I don't know what motherboard you have.

Comment: ok. i have located the driver on asus website and will install now. So is this the cause for BSOD?

Comment: Try to install asus driver. It seems like Nvidia driver is not working in your case. BSOD issue would be related to driver. thats for sure.

Answer (score 1):

Install the latest drivers for your graphics card from the manufacturer site.

Comment: yes i have latest updates installed but the error still persists.

Comment: @user3249242 - **Your dump file says otherwise.**  Post the dxdiag report for us.

Comment: where can i find dxdiag report?

Comment: Click on "START"
Click "run"
Type in "dxdiag" and click "OK"
Check through the tabs and perform all tests
Click "Save all Information..." and save the text file to a location of your choice